# Problema al crear Dataframe en Pandas utilizando Python 3.x

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo varias listas y quiero crear solo un Dataframe para luego exportar.

Las listas son del tipo:

```
    a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    b=[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Para esto estoy creando 2 dataframe de la siguiente forma:

```
    export=pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A'])
    export2=pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['B'])
```

Mi problema es que tengo muchas listas y me gustaría hacer solo un Dataframe de esta forma:

```
    export=pd.DataFrame(a, b, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Pero me tira un error, de dimensión:

```
    ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 600), indices imply (2, 576)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No te funciona porque le estas pasando una lista que es de algun modo como una matriz de 8 columnas y una fila, tu Dataframe tiene 2 columnas 'A' y 'B', por lo que no hay un match de dimensiones.

Aqui tienes varias maneras de hacer lo mismo:

```
# Usando a y b con pandas:
pd.DataFrame([a,b],index=['A','B']).transpose()

# mediante pandas usando export y export2:
pd.concat([export,export2],axis=1,join='inner')

# mediante pandas version 2:
export.join(export2)

# mediante numpy
pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((export,export2)),columns=['A','B'])
```

EDITO: propuesto por @kikocorreoso.

```
# mediante un dict de listas, 

pd.DataFrame(('A':a,'B':b})
```

Lo interesante es si los datos de los que dispones, necesitas unirlos por algún criterio de la tabla en si.

Comment: La forma más, para mi, más evidente y natural: `pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b})`. Lo ideal sería echarle un vistazo a la [documentación](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe).

Comment: Gracias, lo añado a la batería de opciones, no había barajado esa idea. La evidencia y naturalidad son dos conceptos bastante subjetivos. A través de un dict crear un DF, me parece buena idea ;) .